# Angular JS Filter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects that is bound to my HTML with AngularJS.   When a button is clicked, I want to filter the contents of the array and only show certain items in the array.  Each element in the array has several properties and I want to filter on the "mapid" property.  Here is my code:

Map View:

```
<span ng-class="mapArray[0]" ng-click="MapView(0)" class="active">All Maps</span> | 
<span ng-class="mapArray[1]" ng-click="MapView(1)">Public Art</span> | 
<span ng-class="mapArray[2]" ng-click="MapView(2)">City of Houston</span> | 
<span ng-class="mapArray[3]" ng-click="MapView(3)">Gallery Guide</span></p></div>
```

```
var listingsApp = angular.module('listingsApp', []);

listingsApp.controller('pageController', function ($scope, $sce, $filter, $http, $log, $compile) {

$scope.MapView = function (mapviewid) {
    $scope.mapviewid = mapviewid;
    $scope.mapListings = $filter('mapfilter')($scope.allListings, { mapid : mapviewid })
}

})
```

I get an [$injector:unpr] error with this code
angular.min.js:117 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=mapfilterFilterProvider%20%3C-%20mapfilterFilter

Link to controller: https://jsfiddle.net/jpking72/7woyjs67/

Comment: where did you declare `mapfilter` and what is the code/declaration of your controller?

Comment: What does the rest of the error say? Name of the provider should be a big clue

Comment: show us your controller

Comment: @Kenny  There's not much else to show.  I added the original declaration, and $scope.allListings is correct.  I verified with a console.log.

Answer (score 0):

It may be you did not define `mapfilter`, or `mapfilter` is defined in a module you did not declare as a dependency to your module, i.e.

```
 module('myapp', []).filter('mapfilter', function(){ ... })
```

or

```
 module('myapp', ['moduleWithMapFilter'])
```

Comment: won't get `[$injector:unpr]` error if you forget to inject something, only if you inject something that isn't available

Comment: This answer is correct. You are trying to use the filter with name `mapfilter`, but (at least in your question) it isn't clear that the filter is avaiable